# SSIS Table with dynamic number of columns import to flat file

Tags: dynamic, import, ssis, flat

I've got a table with a dynamic number of columns. I have to import this table to flat file everyday. How make SSIS package, that will do this?

Comment: How can a table have a dynamic number of columns?

Comment: This table has not actually dynamic number of columns, just i don't want rebuild my SSIS package when i will add new column to my table

Answer (score 0):

There is way around this, create a view with super set of columns and map to dataflow from source db to flat file destination and after you get the data in flat file. Let me know if you want more details please

Comment: Could you give me more details? In your solution probably i have to rebuild my SSIS package when I add new column

Comment: no you dont need to rebuid as you are not adding or removing any columns from source or destination.

Comment: Could you send me any demo package SSIS or screenshot package?